# Pop up window won't open in Ionic-v1 InAppBrowser

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, popup, android-webview, inappbrowser

I'm new to IONIC and trying to implement payment gateway in my Ionic app. I have everything set up in an external URL, only to load it to the app via InAppBrowser. All looks good especially with Mastercard until a customer decides to use Vis card to make payment which UNFORTUNATELY requires Verified by Visa (VBV/3DS pop up window) as part of its transaction flow.

**NOW THE PROBLEM IS:** pop window won't come up in InAppBrowser. I have tried to use iframe, its all the same thing. I have already looked into [Cordova Documentation on InAppBrowser](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser/) but not helping either.

**in my config:** 
`

```
<access origin="*"/>
  <allow-navigation href="*" />
  <preference name="webviewbounce" value="false"/>
  <preference name="UIWebViewBounce" value="false"/>
  <preference name="DisallowOverscroll" value="true"/>
<preference name="BackupWebStorage" value="none"/>
```

`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After so much effort, I contacted the webpay service provider and they make the redirection (pop up) load on iFrame rather trying to load it on new window. 
This is what solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

TL;DR: The offical Cordova InAppBrowser (IAB) plugin doesn't support popup windows.

I encountered this same problem when trying to display webpages containing the [Braintree JS SDK](https://github.com/braintree/braintree-web) in a Cordova app using the IAB.

[Braintree](https://www.braintreepayments.com) (who are now a subsidiary of PayPal) have created a "PopupBridge" which allows mobile app WebViews to open popup windows in a browser and emulate cross-frame communication between the parent (WebView) and child (browser) pages. There are versions for both [Android](https://github.com/braintree/popup-bridge-android) and [iOS](https://github.com/braintree/popup-bridge-ios). However, their work is targeted at native apps, not Cordova apps.

So I have created [cordova-plugin-inappbrowser-popup-bridge](https://github.com/dpa99c/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser-popup-bridge), which adds support for Braintree's PopupBridge functionality to Cordova's InappBrowser. This makes it possible to support Braintree-powered PayPal payments within the context of the InappBrowser element of Cordova-based Android and iOS apps.

This can be seen working in the [proof-of-concept example Cordova app](https://github.com/dpa99c/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser-popup-bridge-test) I've created which opens the [Braintree PopupBridge Example webpage](https://braintree.github.io/popup-bridge-example) in an IAB WebView.

Braintree's PopupBridge for iOS relies on WKWebView (the new iOS WebView since iOS 8) however the official Cordova IAB plugin still uses the older UIWebView. So in my forked version of IAB, I've rewritten the iOS IAB plugin to use WKWebView instead of UIWebView.

Comment: thank you, the example you posted is somehow complicated. can you please post here sample code that is usable in cordova controller

Comment: I mean, i tried your example and it shows pop up as expected and although it didnt pass value as compared to the one run on browser.

All the same, it looked like you have written a click function that process window.open

but in a case where the payment interface is the one to call the pop up url (automatically) after puting your card details, nothing comes up